# Stop Visual Studio generating log files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition on Windows 10. Simply open and close Visual Studio, and every time one or two new `.tsv` log files are generated at `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SettingsLogs`.

The name of the log files are:

- DATE-TIME-devenv-XXXX.tsv (XXXX is a 4-digit number like "3688")
- DATE-TIME-ServiceHub.SettingsHost-XXXX.tsv (XXXX as above)

In Visual Studio, `Help > Send Feedback > Settings` has been set to "No, I would not like to participate". Every time Visual Studio runs, multiple processes can be seen starting in Task Manager with names like:

- Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller
- ServiceHub.Host.CLR.x86
- ServiceHub.SettingsHost
- ServiceHub.IdentityHost

These shut down when Visual Studio is closed.

Is it possible to stop these log files from being generated? Can these anciliary processes be prevented from starting?

Comment: The ancillary processes are used when debugging and, IIRC, for things like intellisense database maintenance.

Comment: Do you know if some of them are superfluous, though? They look like telemetry processes and not related to debugging. See these registry keys HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Telemetry\PersistentPropertyBag.

Comment: And how to stop these log files? I've opened and closed VS a few times and now have dozens of files, many MBs in total size. They should not be hitting disk!